# Update de datos y envío de correo a la vez

Tags: php, html, sql

Muy buenas chicos, tengo una duda, os lo expongo. Tengo un dashboard para administradores. En he creado varias secciones para ellos, y una de ellas es la sección de alertas. En esa sección de alertas, los administradores hacen un Update al usuario con se alerta correspondiente. El caso es que cuando en el formulario, le den a enviar, se cargue correctamente en la base de datos y envíe un email a ese usuario. El update lo tengo hecho, pero me falta el envío del correo, a ver si me podéis explicar el proceso. Esto es lo que tengo, es una prueba:

```
<?php
include_once '../pruebas/conexion.php';

$sql_leer = 'SELECT id,usuario,apellidos,email FROM usuarios WHERE id';

$gsnet = $pdo->prepare($sql_leer);
$gsnet->execute();

$resultado = $gsnet->fetchAll();


?>
<form action="envio_alerta.php" method="POST">
        <p>Nombre</p>
      <select  class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
        <option selected>Elige opción</option>
        <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>
        <option ><?php echo $dato['usuario']?></option> 
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
        <br>
        <br>
      <p>Apellidos</p>
      <select  class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
      <option selected>Elige opción</option>
       <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>
        <option><?php echo $dato['apellidos']?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Email</p>
      <select name="email" name="id" class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
      <option selected>Elige opción</option>
       <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $dato['id']?>"><?php echo $dato['email']?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?> 
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Texto</p>
      <div class="form-group z-depth-2">

    <textarea name="alerta" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea3" rows="7"></textarea>
</div>
    </div>

        <div class="text-center py-4 mt-3">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-warning waves-effect z-depth-3" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

/*Archivo de envio_alerta.php*/

```
<?php session_start();

include_once '../pruebas/conexion.php';

$alerta = $_POST['alerta'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
 $destino =$_POST['email'];
 $sql_editar = "UPDATE usuarios SET alerta='$alerta' WHERE id='$id'";
 $sentencia_editar = $pdo->prepare($sql_editar);
 $sentencia_editar->execute(array($alerta,$id));

 $contenido= "\nEmail: " . $email . "\nAlerta: " . $alerta;

 mail($destino, "Contacto", $contenido);

 if (mail){
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Tu mensaje ha sido enviado');</script>";

 }


    header('Location: reportes_usuario.php');
```

Comment: Necesitas tener un servidor de correo operativo para que funcione ¿estás en local?

Comment: Si estoy en local. Hice también un formulario de contacto y funciona correctamente, estoy con xammp

Answer (score 0):

Para poder probar el envío de correos en **local** puedes redirigir a localhost y tener alguna utilidad como [papercut](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=papercut) para ver esos correos sin que se lleguen a enviar realmente a los destinatarios.

1. Verifica que en "ruta_xampp\php\php.ini" la línea sendmail_path no está comentada y apunta correctametne al ejecutable de sendmail (suele venir con los paquetes de xampp) Por ejemplo debería decir algo como `sendmail_path = "\"\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"`
2. Verifica que en "ruta_xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini" `smtp_server=127.0.0.1` y `smtp_port=25`
3. Ejecuta Papercut, que se encargará de "recibir" los correos que envíes sin que estos se envíen realmente a los destinatarios (así no les molestas con pruebas ;-)).

NOTA: Si el puerto 25 estuviera capado, puedes poner otro. Pero en papercut tendrás que ir a opciones y poner el mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, aun así, como sería el código en php, si por ejemplo estoy en un hosting.

Comment: El código php es el mismo que en local. Lo único que cambia es que configuras tu xampp local para enviar los correos a localhost. Y en localhost, tu pc, tienes una utilidad para 'recibir' (y ver) esos correos. Cuando subas tu código php a tu servicio de hosting no tienes que hacer nada más. Cuando envíes un correo se utilizarán los valores configurados por tu hosting.

Comment: si el es mismo, pero no me resuelves la duda de si mi código está bien para que funcione.